# retrofit is returning 404 not found

Tags: android, http-status-code-404, retrofit

this is my class where retrofit is called.

```
public class Prelist_fragment extends ListActivity {
String API = "http://nisani.net/nisani hoarding/";
String tag;
Datum datum;

private ArrayList<String> stores = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e(tag, "in oncreate of prelist");
    retro();


}


void retro(){
    Log.e(tag, "inside retro");
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(API).build();                                        //create an adapter for retrofit with base url

    gitapi git = restAdapter.create(gitapi.class);
    git.getStores("hij",new Callback<PreStoreResponse>() {


        @Override
        public void success(PreStoreResponse preStoreResponse, Response response) {

            stores.add(datum.getStore());
            TextView tView = new TextView(Prelist_fragment.this);
            getListView().addHeaderView(tView);

            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Prelist_fragment.this,
                    R.layout.activity_prelist_fragment,stores));
            getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.e(tag, "inside retro error"+error.getUrl()+" "+error.getMessage());
            if (error.isNetworkError()) {
                Log.e(tag,"network error"); // Use another code if you'd prefer
            }

        }

    });
}
```

and this is my interface.

```
public interface gitapi {


/* GET LIST*/

@GET("/pre_report.php") //a function in your api to get all the list
public void getStores(@Query("roll")String a,Callback<PreStoreResponse> response);
}
```

when i tried this, it is showing 404 not found. the url is correct, i checked that. the response is going on onfailure of retrofit not on onsuccess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first guess would be that Retrofit is failing because of the space in your endpoint URL.

When typing it into a browser, the browser automatically converts that space into '%20', which it then understands. I'm not sure that Retrofit is able to do the same. Retrofit might simply be removing that space, converting your original URL into "http://nisani.net/nisanihoarding/", which obviously gives a 404 error.

Try and change your endpoint URL to:
http://nisani.net/nisani%20hoarding/